# IONIC Property does not exist in own object in all my html files

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am still getting to know angular and ionic and I have a strange question I cannot seem to find the solution for.

I have a few export classes, with a few html pages with forms. I declare a variable in the .ts files behind each form and I import the relevant model to the form. I  use the variable to bind to the forms in both my angular and ionic apps so that I can post to my backend. The angular app runs perfectly fine but for some reason the ionic serve throws messages like these in every place I use ngModel binding:

```
RROR in src/app/vet/vet.component.html:15:81 - error TS2339: Property 'adress' does not exist on type 'School'.

  15           <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="adress" [(ngModel)]="school1.adress"  required>
```

in the .ts file linked to the html file I do have:

```
import { School } from '../Model/Schools';
```

And I declare the following

```
 school1 = new School('','','');
```

in my Model/Schools.ts:

```
    export class School{
constructor(public sc_ID: string,public  name:string,public  adress:string){

  }
}
```

Any idea why angular is fine with this but my ionic app throws all these errors?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the full component- but I think you have to import the types(interfaces) in any place(ts-file) you use it. Make sure that you delclare school1 as public. Eventually use an extra Variable for the input-binding.

For the output-bindings you can use a ngFor to access the members of school1:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of school1">
…
item.name

</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, I forgot to add public decorators to the variables in the constructor parameters

it should be

```
    export class School{
constructor(public sc_ID: string,public  name:string,public  adress:string){

  }
}
```